# Django queryset dates: aggregate and format months as name strings

Tags: django, formatting, aggregate-functions

I've got a simple blog application which I'm porting to Django. One stumbling block I've come across is the aggregation of article entries by month, and displaying that as a list. Each article in the db has a simple datetime field. The HTML output should be something like:

### 2010

- January (3 entries)
- February (2 entries)
- March (3 entries)

etc.

I'm currently using a {% foreach %} block in the template to loop through all the months returned from the query.

Going with dates('datestamp','month') seems to be the right direction, but how do I get article counts in the results, and how would I format the month integers to be name strings in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-cube](http://code.google.com/p/django-cube/) for this. With the following code in your views.py (and then connect `entry_count` in your urls), you should get what you need :

```
# cube declaration
from cube.models import Cube, Dimension

class EntryCube(Cube):

    #replace <your_date_field> by the field name
    month = Dimension('<your_date_field>__month') 
    year = Dimension('<your_date_field>__year')

    @staticmethod
    def aggregation(queryset):
        return queryset.count()

# views declaration
from .models import <YourModel> #replace by your model
from cube.views import table_from_cube

def entry_count(request):
    cube = EntryCube(<YourModel>.objects.all())
    return table_from_cube(request, cube, ['year', 'month'], template='table.html')
    #template 'table.html' is in 'example/template' folder, copy it in your template folder, and modify it to your wish.
```

---

EDIT :

If you want to customize the way dimensions are displayed, you can just subclass `Dimension` (see this [snippet](http://django-cube.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/snippets.html#override-the-display-for-a-dimension)):

```
class MonthDimension(Dimension):

    @property
    def pretty_constraint(self):
        #just return the month name according to the month number that you can get in "self.constraint", e.g. self.constraint = 1 -> return 'january'
        return month_name
```

(I plan to provide subclasses of dimensions to allow different formats like what you need. So if you do use django-cube, and write a good subclass of `Dimension` to format dates, I would be happy to take a look at it !)

---

Ok ... it is overkill for what you want. However, if you decide after that you want more statistics on your entries (for example number of entries/author/month/year/tag, etc ...), you simply add a dimension to the cube. If you decide to use this, and need more help, please ask !

Comment: Thanks, looks like a useful tool. Any ideas on the how to convert numerical months to month names question?

Comment: Still just trying to get the actual cube data bit to work. Currently getting the following exception: http://dpaste.com/269188/. 

Is a tabular output the only available output, or would I be able to put the results in to a <ul>?

Comment: Ow ... actually I think your error doesn't come from cube : you wrote (Article.objects.filter('type'!='NEWS')), and this cannot work (I guess you meant : Article.objects.exclude(type='NEWS')). Actually, you can output however you want. The view `table_from_cube` just renders the template you give it with a special context. See : http://django-cube.googlecode.com/hg/doc/html/api_doc.html#cube.query.CubeQueryMixin.table_helper , and you have the reference of all the variables that are set. Then just write your own custom template with this.

Comment: Progress! I've got the Queryset returning something sane now. A new exception - not implemented. Definately from cube...: http://dpaste.com/269204/

Comment: hahaha ... Haven't you forgotten to override the `aggregate` method of your cube ?

Comment: I had a typo: def aggregate(queryset): instead of def aggregation(queryset):

Comment: Ooh !!! Actually my mistake, it is not `aggregate` but `aggregation` I edited the answer